# What gems/plugins can be used for Unsubscribe support in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, unsubscribe

What gems/plugins that make it easy to add a tamper-resistant unsubscribe link to the bottom of the email a user can click to prevent receiving email those types of emails?

The only thing I could find was http://kevinlochner.com/handling-unsubscribe-requests-in-ruby-on-rail  which works but is somewhat unsophisticated and lacks features such as which type of emails to unsubscribe from.  It also doesnt include the mechanism for users to unsubscribe.

EDIT: This gem helps with preventing mail delivery, but no unsubscribe link support. github.com/myronmarston/email_blacklist

We've implemented this ourselves using a combination of the email_blacklist gem and an unsubscribe model/controller with HMAC authentication

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a standard gem for this yet, especially since a search for "unsubscribe" on rubygems.org returns 2 gems, neither of which have anything to do with e-mail subscriptions. Sounds like you get to implement this yourself. Congrats.

Consider building your implementation as a generic gem that you configure to your own needs, so that you can distribute it to the world and help those who have this problem in the future. After all, that's how all gems end up getting built: someone has to be the first to want it, then be willing to make it.

Of course, if you're running on deadline, it might be better just to hack something together for your specific app. In that case, get 'er done, and move to the next feature.